# Grouping values from my_ MySQL to be shown in separate <div> on the basis of certain criteria

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a php project with MySQL as database. Here is the table structure

```
product_id (PK)
shop_id (FK)
product_name
product_desc
```

Product_id is the primary key and shop_id is the foreign key (shows the product belongs to which shop). Now I want to select these product and display them in a `<div>`. For each shop products, I want to display a different `<div>`. e.g if there are three products say p1,p2 and p3, and they have same shop_id (say) 1, i want them to show in a separate `<div>`. there will be separate `<div>` for each shop_id, and all products belong to that shop_id will be displayed in that `<div>`. How can I do this with My_SQL query or using PHP. I have used a simple SELECT query like this but with this i could not find a way to initiate different `<div>` for separate shop.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
echo "<div>";
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
echo $product['product_name']."<br/>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

It just throw all products in a single dive, I want separate div for separate shop (which contains all products of that shop). Thanks for reading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to group the products by id in a array and loop through them

```
$all_products = array();
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $all_products[$product['shop_id']][] = $product;
}

foreach($all_products as $shop_id => $product_array){
echo "<div id='shop_".$shop_id."'>";
   foreach($product_array as $product){
      echo $product['product_name']."<br/>";
    }
echo "</div>";
}
```

OR call product data fro each shop id

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shops");

while($shops = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
       $product_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE shop_id=$shops['id']");
       echo "<div>";
       while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_q)){
           echo $product['product_name']."<br/>";
           }
       echo "</div>";

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Elijan, this concept looks similar to inception movie, "an array of arrays for array, we must go deeper." :-) but it solved my problem...

Comment: @WaqarAkbar . lol yeah. I ve updated the comment fro different and more elegant  solution, you can query the shop products by shop id as generally it is not good to do select *

Comment: So instead of *, I should use each column name... Is there any problem with using select *..???

Comment: @WaqarAkbar Ideally, yes if you will use only that coulmn. Depending on operation that column should be indexed in database for faster queering.

so, for example `$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM shops");` and then later `mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product_table WHERE shop_id=$shops['id']");`  where both shops.id and products.shop_id are indexed

Comment: This make lots of sense, will try to follow it... Thanks for help.